# Dynamic Routing in react does not render, trows weird error in console

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I think my problem is almost the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)
But might be a bit different and I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I am assuming I dont understand react-router-dom v6.0 and that is whats causing the issue.

Component:

```
const RouterComponenet = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route  index path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/documents" element={<Documents />}/>
      <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />}/>
      <Route path="/pdf/:id" element={<Pdf />}/>
   </Routes>
  );
}
```

For manuall enter "https//localhost.com:3000/pdf/223321"
I am getting this error inside a console:

```
index.js:1 error loading SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

But if there is

```
<Link to="pdf/223321" >
```

Works fine.

But if i click on  element and after opening page I hit refresh, same error as if manual entry

I have tried couple of things.

- I tried configuring .htaccess file as instructed in the question I linked.
- I tried addin hashHistory inside routes as instructed on most upvoted answer. I dont have hasHistory inside react-router-dom@6.0.2 `Attempted import error: 'hashHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.`

Is it same problem and how to solve it without ejecting webpack? That is only solution I want to avoid if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Mladen might it would help, I was also using react-router-dom@6 and getting same issue after making build, dynamic pages weren't working

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Footer from './components/layout/Footer';
import OfferList from './components/offers/OfferList';
import SingleSlugOffer from './components/offers/SingleSlugOffer';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<OfferList />} />
          {/* <Route path="/:category/:postid" element={<SingleOffer />} /> */}
          <Route path="/:category/:slug" element={<SingleSlugOffer />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But in my case, I was using `<a href={}></a>` for linking the pages and after your suggestion, I replaced it with `<Link to={}></Link>` and my dynamic pages are working fine, also thanks for your solution

Old Linking:

```
<a href={`${fullUrl}/${attributes.categories.data[0].attributes.categoryslug}/${attributes.slug}`}>View Offer</a>
```

Replaced by:

```
<Link to={`${attributes.categories.data[0].attributes.categoryslug}/${attributes.slug}`}>View Offer</Link>
```